# Proxies attribute in Requests module is ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm building a small script to test the certain proxies against the API.

It seems that the actual request isn't trigger under the provided proxy. For example, the following request will be valid and I will get an response from the API.

```
import requests

r = requests.post("https://someapi.com", data=request_data,
                  proxies={"http": "http://999.999.999.999:1212"}, timeout=5)
print(r.text)
```

How come I get the response even if the proxy provided was invalid?

Comment: The problem was that I was calling the `https` and configuring the proxy for `http`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the proxies like this;

```
import requests

pxy = "http://999.999.999.999:1212"
proxyDict = {
    'http': pxy,
    'https': pxy,
    'ftp': pxy,
    'SOCKS4': pxy
}

r = requests.post("https://someapi.com", data=request_data,
                  proxies=proxyDict, timeout=5)

print(r.text)
```